# Python: How to import part of a namespace

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I have a structure such this works :

```
import a.b.c
a.b.c.foo()
```

and this also works :

```
from a.b import c
c.foo()
```

but this doesn't work :

```
from a import b.c
b.c.foo()
```

nor does :

```
from a import b
b.c.foo()
```

How can I do the import so that `b.c.foo()` works?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need the b.c.foo() syntax instead of c.foo() for your code?

Comment: yes, the prefix is really long with lots of nested modules, but importing 'c' is a namespace collision.

Comment: ok, adding to that, assume that it is more semantically correct to write c.foo() so that we can't skirt the problem.

Comment: namespace collisions are easier to solve with a `from a.b import c as b_c` and similar renamings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just rename it:

```
from a.b import c as BAR

BAR.foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your '`b`' package, you need to add '`import c`' so that it is always accessible as part of `b`.

Comment: Then b has to guess all the submodules that you would ever want to use on it? The code is in c, shouldn't there be a better way?

Answer (score 2):

```
from a import b
from a.b import c
b.c = c
```

Comment: Not sure what "monkeypatching the code" means -- it's monkeypatching module (package) b to remedy the fact that it doesn't, apparently, import its own c sub-module.

Comment: BTW, the intermediate name could also be changed with an `as`, of course, whether you then monkeypatch it back in as `b.c` or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
import a.b.c
from a import b
b.c.foo()
```

The order of the import statements doesn't matter.